# Limit input speed

Tags: vim

Is it possible to restrict the speed of input in vim itself (not os)?

To sort of simulate editing session over slow network connection.

Comment: Maybe bind every key in insert mode to switch to edit mode, then back to insert mode and insert the character :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * :sleep 200m
```

Which causes Vim to pause for 200 milliseconds every time the cursor moves in normal or insert mode.  This won't work for the :-command line or in a few other contexts.

See:

```
:help :autocomd
:help CursorMoved
:help :sleep
```